# Download multiple SRA files

Tags: rna-seq, data-download

I want to download all SRA file from the following [project](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra?linkname=bioproject_sra_all&from_uid=201245). Is there a method to download all the SRA files at the same time?

Comment: You could use the R/Bioconductor package [SRAdb](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/SRAdb.html)

Comment: @JohnBlischak This might be an answer if expanded explaining how SRAdb helps to answer the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick look at your link tells me the SRR numbers run from SRR837819 to SRR837856. You can use fastq-dump from the sratoolkit, and make a for loop around it in bash.

Something like this should work:

```
for (( i = 19; i <= 56; i++ ))
  do
  fastq-dump --accession SRR8378$i
done
```

After reading [Devon Ryan](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/users/77/devon-ryan)'s answer, I realize that you asked for SRA files instead of fastq. This can also be done with prefetch of the sratoolkit:

```
for (( i = 19; i <= 56; i++ ))
  do
  prefetch SRR8378$i
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you ultimately just want the fastq files and you know the SRR (run) numbers, I would download them from here: ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/

As for downloading multiple files, I've just used multiple wget commands. I don't know of a way to download all of the files together in like a zipped folder or anything :/

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you follow the advice in [Eric A Brenner's](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/users/1628/eric-a-brenner) answer and just download the fastq files. However, if you really really want to use the SRA files for some reason, note that you can use [parallel-fastq-dump](https://github.com/rvalieris/parallel-fastq-dump) to make things faster. Do follow its advice regarding using `prefetch`.

You'd need to combine that with the answer from [b.nota](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/users/939/b-nota) (i.e., put the commands in a `for` loop).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution for this using [Entrez Direct](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK179288/) and SRA toolkit :) If you have the project number or [SRA project number](https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/?study=SRP022054), yours would be SRP022054 in this case for the 36 SRAs, you can use esearch to make a query like so and pipe it into SRA toolkit with this one liner:

`esearch -db sra -query SRP022054  | efetch --format runinfo | cut -d ',' -f 1 | grep SRR | head -5 | xargs fastq-dump  --skip-technical  --readids --read-filter pass --dumpbase --split-3`

Answer (score 0):

You can download an entire project using [pysradb](https://github.com/saketkc/pysradb):

```
pysradb download -p SRP022054
```

It retains the same schema as SRA.

Answer (score 0):

Once you [install SRA tools](https://github.com/ncbi/sra-tools/wiki/02.-Installing-SRA-Toolkit), you can grab a BioProject/SRP accession list (Send to - File - Accession List) and save it to default SRA tools /sra directory, then run (with /sra as cwd):

```
prefetch --option-file SraAccList.txt
cat SraAccList.txt | xargs fasterq-dump --outdir "/your-directory/for-fastq"
```

P.S. The text file can be any list of accessions, separated by return.
Tested in Bash

Answer (score 0):

This online tool creates download links for the less tech savy:

https://sra-explorer.info/#

Using PRJNA201245 as ID, it provides several codes including a bash script for downloading all files.